# JS – stopping multiple youtube videos when another one starts playing

Tags: javascript, arrays, iframe, youtube

I'm using the following code (written by my friend, I'm a beginner in JS) to create several iframes with different youtube videos, which I can then link to from within the text with the seekTo(t) function –

```
var players = [];

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    YTready()
}

function createPlayer(ref, divID, videoID) {
    players[ref] = new YT.Player(divID, {
        height: '360',
        width: '640',
        videoId: videoID,
        events: {}
    });
}

function jumpToTimecode(ref,t){
    for(var i=0;i<players.length;i++){
        if(i!=ref){
            players[i].stopVideo()
        }
    }
    players[ref].seekTo(t)
    players[ref].playVideo()
}
```

It includes a way to stop all other videos once the user clicks on the link. What I'd like to do is add a function that would do the same thing (stop all other videos on the page) if the user simply clicks the play button on one of the youtube players.

I was thinking of defining an 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange event in the createPlayer function, and then adding a function that upon any of the players changing their state to playing // if (event.data == 1) // would loop through all the players and stop any which were not the one which was clicked. I'm not sure, though, how to reference the player which was clicked (as it could be any of them, so I don't know its 'ref' value in advance).

Or is this the wrong way to approach this? 
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I solved this (with my friend's help).

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if(event.data == 1) {
        var ref = event.target.f.id
        for(var i=0;i<players.length;i++){
        if(players[i].f.id != ref){
            players[i].stopVideo()
        }
      }
   }
}
```

with the event.target.f.id being the unique id given (by me) to the player as it's created.